# Reaching variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, hover

I have a code like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentPicture;//default picture
    var picEL;//the image viewer element
    jQuery("#backImageShower").hover(
        function(i)
        {
            picEL = jQuery("#dynloadarxdock > img");
            currentPicture = picEL.attr("src");
            picEl.attr("src","back.jpg");
        },
        function()
        {
            picEl.attr("src",currentPicture);
        }
    );
</script>
```

But when I run this code, it says `picEl` is not defined. I think it could be because of closures but this code runs perfectly :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentPicture;//default picture
    jQuery("#backImageShower").hover(
        function(i)
        {
            currentPicture = jQuery("#dynloadarxdock > img").attr("src");
            jQuery("#dynloadarxdock > img").attr("src","back.jpg");
        },
        function()
        {
            jQuery("#dynloadarxdock > img").attr("src",currentPicture);
        }
    );
</script>
```

But also this code includes global variable and it works.

Can somebody tell me why?

Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't use `i` for non-loop variables. The first argument of an event handler is usually an event so better call it `e`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: indeed. In `hover` it is an event, and it isn't used either, so it could be dropped altogether, as in the second callback passed to `hover`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're mixing the casing. The variable is declared as `picEL` but sometimes used as `picEl` (lowercase 'l', which is where your error is).

Answer (score 0):

You are using picEl and not picEL.

```
 picEl.attr("src",currentPicture);
```

should be:

```
 picEL.attr("src",currentPicture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using picEL everywhere except in the second hover function where you have - picEl.